# Querying and rendering an HTML table of ISP performance statistics

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have multiples measurements and I want to render it into tables like this

| Measurements |  |  | Operator | browsings |  |  | FTP DL |  |  | FTP UL |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | Event | Date | Operator | avg | min | max | avg | min | max | avg | min | max |
|  |  |  | Verizon |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | USCell |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | T-Mobile |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

for each measurement rendered there is always 3 operator

the operator is fixed/determined value
they are `["Verizon", "USCell", "T-Mobile"]`

my current approach is to use multiple loop and using `where` clause to achieve this

`measurements/index.html.erb`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Measurement</th>
      <th colspan="3">FTP DL</th>
      <th colspan="3">FTP UL</th>
      <th colspan="3">Browsing</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Average Browsing Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Minimum Browsing Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Maximum Browsing Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Average FTP Download Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Minimum FTP Download Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Maximum FTP Download Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Average FTP Upload Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Minimum FTP Upload Speed (Mbps)</th>
      <th>Maximum FTP Upload Speed (Mbps)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @measurements.each do |measurement| %>
      <% @operators.each do |operator| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= measurement.location %></td>
          <td><%= measurement.event %></td>
          <td><%= measurement.date %></td>
          <td><%= operator %></td>
          <% if measurement.browsings.where(operator: operator).any? %>
            <td><%= measurement.browsings.where(operator: operator).first.avg %></td>
            <td><%= measurement.browsings.where(operator: operator).first.min %></td>
            <td><%= measurement.browsings.where(operator: operator).first.max %></td>
          <% else %>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          <% end %>
          <% if measurement.ftp_dls.where(operator: operator).any? %>
            <td><%= measurement.ftp_dls.where(operator: operator).first.avg %></td>
            <td><%= measurement.ftp_dls.where(operator: operator).first.min %></td>
            <td><%= measurement.ftp_dls.where(operator: operator).first.max %></td>
          <% else %>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          <% end %>
          <% if measurement.ftp_uls.where(operator: operator).any? %>
            <td><%= measurement.ftp_uls.where(operator: operator).first.avg %></td>
            <td><%= measurement.ftp_uls.where(operator: operator).first.min %></td>
            <td><%= measurement.ftp_uls.where(operator: operator).first.max %></td>
          <% else %>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm wondering if I could avoid using multiple loop and where clause on my code to achieve this?

because I think using multiple loop and where approach considered it as bad practices, isn't it?

I'm thinking since I have multiple repeated `operator` I could use that as a group or something, I'm thinking about joining all my `has_many` and group them by using `group_by operator` but I don't know how to do it yet (need a little guidance there if its really possible and good approach)

here are my others code

`measurement.rb`

```
class Measurement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ftp_uls, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ftp_dls, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :browsings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`measurement_controller.rb`

```
class MeasurementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_measurement, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def index
    @measurements = Measurement.all
    @operators = ["Verizon", "USCell", "T-Mobile"]
  end
end
```

`schema.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_08_17_062327) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "browsings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "measurement_id", null: false
    t.string "operator"
    t.decimal "avg"
    t.decimal "min"
    t.decimal "max"
    t.index ["measurement_id"], name: "index_browsings_on_measurement_id"
  end

  create_table "ftp_dls", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "measurement_id", null: false
    t.string "operator"
    t.decimal "avg"
    t.decimal "min"
    t.decimal "max"
    t.index ["measurement_id"], name: "index_ftp_dls_on_measurement_id"
  end

  create_table "ftp_uls", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "measurement_id", null: false
    t.string "operator"
    t.decimal "avg"
    t.decimal "min"
    t.decimal "max"
    t.index ["measurement_id"], name: "index_ftp_uls_on_measurement_id"
  end

  create_table "measurements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "location"
    t.string "event"
    t.date "date"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the first problem I'd try to address is that you're running SQL queries in your views. This is generally considered a bad practice (and there are helpful gems/frameworks that will throw errors if you try to do this).

The second major issue is the # of sql queries being run, as we're executing multiple queries for each measurement (1+N problem). This is the source of your performance issue in both the original example and your updated code.

Ideally you want all the relevant data to be loaded in a small number of SQL queries ahead of time.

It looks like you want 1 row per measurement per operator (is that right?). This is not easy to do with your current database schema. I've added a sql query that builds this but it's complex. This could be a great use case for a SQL view with an activerecord object on top of it.

I'm also assuming you only have at most 1 row per measurement + operator combo in the browsings/ftp_dls/ftp_uls tables. If this is correct, I'd add a unique index to enforce this on each table. If there could be multiple rows per operator and measurement then you'll need to adjust the SQL or this will return duplicate rows.

So I'd start by building SQL queries that generates the data you want. Something like...

```
@operators = ["Verizon", "USCell", "T-Mobile"]

# You don't need to hard-code the operators but I thought it made
# the SQL easier to understand
operator_join_sql = <<-SQL
  INNER JOIN (('Verizon'),('USCell'),('T-Mobile')) 
  AS operators(name) 
  ON true
SQL
browsings_join_sql = <<-SQL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN browsings ON browsings.operator = operators.name 
  AND browsings.measurment_id = measurements.id
SQL
ftp_uls_join_sql = <<-SQL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ftp_uls ON ftp_uls.operator = operators.name 
  AND ftp_uls.measurment_id = measurements.id
SQL
ftp_dls_join_sql = <<-SQL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ftp_dls ON ftp_dls.operator = operators.name 
  AND ftp_dls.measurment_id = measurements.id
SQL
select_sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT measurements.*
  , operators.name AS operator
  , browsings.avg AS ftp_urls_avg
  , browsings.min AS ftp_urls_min
  , browsings.max AS ftp_urls_max
  , ftp_urls.avg AS ftp_urls_avg
  , ftp_urls.min AS ftp_urls_min
  , ftp_urls.max AS ftp_urls_max
  , ftp_drls.avg AS ftp_drls_avg
  , ftp_drls.min AS ftp_drls_min
  , ftp_drls.max AS ftp_drls_max
SQL

@measurement_by_operator = @measurements.select(select_sql)
  .joins(operator_join_sql)
  .joins(browsings_join_sql)
  .joins(ftp_uls_join_sql)
  .joins(ftp_dls_join_sql)
```

Then, in your view, you would do:

```
<% @measurement_by_operator.each do |measurement| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= measurement.location %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.event %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.date %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.operator %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.browsings_avg %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.browsings_min %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.browsings_max %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.ftp_uls_avg %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.ftp_uls_min %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.ftp_uls_max %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.ftp_dls_avg %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.ftp_dls_min %></td>
    <td><%= measurement.ftp_dls_max %></td>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

#### ---- EDIT ----

Some additional thoughts on your data schema...

Your three tables (browsings, ftp_uls, fpt_dls) have identical schema. They could be a single table (e.g. "measurement_readings" with a a "type" column, for example).

While the first approach I'm suggesting is probably best, it's fairly advanced. With the readings in a single table, there's an alternative that might be more approachable and still reasonable. Something like:

**In your model (or better, a helper or presenter!)**

```
class Measurement
  def for(operator, type)
    measurement_readings.detect{|mr| mr.operator == operator && mr.type == type } || NullMeasurementReading.new
  end
end
# A `NullMeasurementReading` is just a nullobject pattern. Could be a PORO or subclass of MeasurementReading or whatever.
# Alternatively use `&.` in the view.
# We're using `detect` here because we expect the array of readings to already be loaded 
# and explicitly *do not* want to trigger SQL queries
```

**your controller**

```
@measurements = @measurements.preload(:measurement_readings)
```

**in the view**

```
<% @measurements.each do |measurement| %>
  <% operators.each do |operator| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= measurement.location %></td>
      <td><%= measurement.event %></td>
      <td><%= measurement.date %></td>
      <td><%= operator %></td>
      <td><%= measurement.for(operator, 'browsings').avg %>
      <td><%= measurement.for(operator, 'browsings').min %>
      <td><%= measurement.for(operator, 'browsings').max %>
      <%# etc.. %>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes I want 1 row per measurement per operator, should I change my database schema then? and yes it also unique 1 measurement only have 3 operator for each type of measurement

Comment: Your current database schema makes rendering this report difficult (an issue can be addressed fairly well with a view). It may make other things easy. Evaluating what database schema is best for an application is difficult, and changes over time as the needs of the application change. It's impossible for me to say.

Comment: That having been said - having three tables with identical column names/types is definitely a design-smell to me and I'd be quick to refactor those into a single table with a type field. If you want different activerecord models (although I'd question why) you can use STI and keep them separate.

Answer (score -2):

there is many way to refactor this

first change operator into integer/enum instead string, or change operator to become an object/table instead with a `name` and `order` column

so that we can sort the browsings/ftpdl/ftp ul using `operator` column more easier

then to simplify the loop and query we can transform it into and array first then render the table row/data from that array

the new `measurement_controller.rb` `index` method would be like this

```
def index
  @measurements = Measurement.all #we could also add eager loading here 
                 #Measurement.all.includes(:browsings, :ftp_dls, :ftp_uls)
  @rows = []
  @measurements.each do |measurement|
    row = []
    Operator.all.each_with_index do |operator, index|
      row << [measurement.location, measurement.event, measurement.date, operator.name]
    end
    measurement.browsings.each_with_index do |browsing, index|
      row[index].concat([browsing.avg, browsing.min, browsing.max])
    end 
    measurement.ftp_dls.each_with_index do |ftp_dl, index| 
      row[index].concat([ftp_dl.avg, ftp_dl.min, ftp_dl.max])
    end
    measurement.ftp_uls.each_with_index do |ftp_ul, index|
      row[index].concat([ftp_ul.avg, ftp_ul.min, ftp_ul.max])
    end
    @rows << row
  end 
  @rows = @rows.flatten(1)
end
```

the new `measurements/index.html.erb` `<tbody>` table render would be like this

```
<tbody>
  <% @rows.each do |row|%>
    <tr>
      <% row.each do |data| %>
        <td><%= data %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end%>
</tbody>
```

I think it will perform faster than the code before and the code is more readable and also we avoid loop inside loop idk but people said loop inside loop is bad

I just test it and in my use case it reduce the load time from `266693.0 ms` to `13103.0 ms` and to `7432.4 ms` with eager loading

Comment: why the downvotes? can you give me some comment/edit suggestion?

Comment: So - this code doesn't work. Even if you order by operator, unless we know that 100% of the data exists for each operator and measurement (which your initial code assumes is not the case) then the operators won't always be at the same index. For example, if you order "Verizon", "USCell", "T-Mobile" but there's no "Verizon" data then it would be "USCell" with `index:0`

Comment: Another issue is that if you use eager-load it joins measurements to browsings to ftp_uls to ftp_dls, you're doing: measurement x 3 browsings x 3 ftp_uls x3 ftp_dls, so you're creating a table 27x larger than the measurements table (9x larger than necessary) and then rails is going through the results and de-duping the rows. This is all very costly/time intensive.

Comment: Even if you fix the logical problem and ensure that it's building a nested array - there's a big implicit coupling of the order of the columns in the view / table to the positional order of the fields you're putting into each row. It's impossible to know why the fields are added in that order unless you know the order of the columns in the view. This is makes our backend implementation tightly coupled to the front-end, which is bad.

Comment: ok I'll refactor it later